# unable to remove file using WIX tool

Tags: wix

I am trying to remove file using .wxs file (WIX Tool) on install, but it is not removing anything.

Please check below command and let me know where it is wrong?

```
<Component Id="Comp" Guid="MYGUID" Directory="test">
    <RemoveFile Id="rem1" Name="*.zip" On="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

Comment: You wrote _on install_ but then wrote `On="uninstall"` so which one do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Use [RemoveFile Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html) On="**uninstall**". Here's an example:

```
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder" Name="CommonAppDataFolder">
  <Directory Id="MyAppFolder" Name="My">
    <Component Id="MyAppFolder" Guid="*">
      <CreateFolder />
      <RemoveFile Id="PurgeAppFolder" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

**Hope this is helpful :)**